# Recursion/Pattern Matching to evaluate a Postfix expression in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack, pattern-matching

I am taking an introduction functional programming class, and we are tasked to evaluate a postfix expression in Haskell using a stack. We have covered pattern matching, guards, and recursion so far however I am still struggling to understand how to use Haskell to achieve this. The input of the project is a [String] array, for example ["59","14","-"] (simplest case). We are tasked to solve this which would be 59-14= 45 and return it as a string. The method stub we are given is shown below called "evaluate". What I understand so far is that if the element in the array is not an operator, I need to push to a stack, which I created a method for called "push" but that is obviously wrong. If the element is an operator I need to pop two numbers from the stack and perform the operation, then push it back on the stack. I also understand that I need to recursively call the function evaluate to see all the input. My question is how do I use a stack in Haskell to push numbers, then pop them when I see an operator. For some reason it does not make sense to me in a functional approach. I am just looking for some guidance on this simplest case so I can build from there. I am not sure how to exactly push to a stack then recursively call my "evaluate" function with the rest of the array.  Also apologize if this is a bad post, this is my first time asking on here.
Thanks

```
-- Your implementation goes here. Feel free to add more functions.
evaluate :: [String] -> String
evaluate []  = "" 
evaluate("-":xs) = "-"        
evaluate(a:xs) = do 
         push a []
        --/would I call evaluate here?


push::[String]->[Int]->String
push (x:xs) [] = [x]
--not sure what to do after this
```

I have tried to create a method called push, that pushes a number to the stack, but I am not sure how to actually push the element on a stack, then recursively call my evaluate function. Maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way.

Comment: try to minimize question further. It doesn't help only in getting help, it's also what programming is about. Start with one particular thing, sounds like that stack operation could be it.

Answer (score 2):

Your stack is supposed to return a list: the new stack, so you push an item with:

```
push:: String -> [Int] -> [Int]
push x xs = read x : xs
```

or shorter:

```
push:: String -> [Int] -> [Int]
push = (:) . read
```

as for the `evaluate` function, you will need to make use of a helper function that you initialize with an empty stack. You then walk through the list and update the accumulator: the stack until you reach the end of the list of strings to then return the peek of the stack:

```
evaluate :: [String] -> String
evaluate  = go []
    where go (x:_) [] = …
          go (x1:x2:xs) ("-":ys) = …
          -- ⋮
          go xs (y:ys) = go (push y xs) ys
```

here for the last line we thus push `y` on the stack `xs` and recurse with the new stack as first parameter, and the rest of the items of the list as remaining items. The `…` and `⋮` parts still need to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot, now I am able to go and do further operations, it makes more sense now.